# How to cross compile freetype library for android in Windows?

Tags: android, android-ndk, freetype

I'm trying to use freetype library in my native android application. But the only information about using this library with android ndk I found works only on *nix systems:

http://blog.beuc.net/posts/Cross-compile_FreeType_for_Android_ARM/

or

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Installation/Android#FreeType

In other words, I can't perform cross-compiling procedure on windows system.

Is there any step-by-step reference about it or is it possible to download already cross-compiled version of freetype library?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

When you are working with ndk under window systems you have to use cygwin for compilation, that is anyway *nix system.

You can do compilation using cygwin

Please refer this link

http://mindtherobot.com/blog/452/android-beginners-ndk-setup-step-by-step/

Comment: Of course I tried, but it didn't work for me... I've failed to compiule it at first step:

make-standalone-toolchain.sh --platform=android-9 --install-dir=/cygdrive/c/DEV/ndk-standalone-9  
/cygdrive/c/DEV/AndroidNDK/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh: line 18: dirname: command not found             
/cygdrive/c/DEV/AndroidNDK/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh: line 18: /prebuilt-common.sh: No such file or di
rectory

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this project](https://code.google.com/p/indic-text-renderer/) which uses freetype, as I have managed to compile it succesfully using cygwin.